timefold: shadow variable and clone
I have model:

PlanningEntity SelectionNode with PlanningVariable SelectionVariant
SelectionVariant with field List of SelectionTeam
SelectionTeam

The option with List of SelectionTeam in SelectionNode (without SelectionVariant) does not suit me since it is not just any set of SelectionTeams, but only specified variants.
And I need a list of SelectionNode in SelectionTeam.
There are some examples with two class (like FlightAssignment and Employee), but how I can use shadow variable in my case?
I try to add @ShadowVariable (with VariableListener) on list of SelectionNode in SelectionTeam, but when i try to use this collection (list of SelectionNode) I get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException, I think because it does not clone when solution clone.

From the Timefold docs, you can add @DeepPlanningClone to the SelectionTeam class, which will cause it to be cloned (and thus clone its list of SelectionNode planning entities).
However, I doubt the ConcurrentModificationException is caused by not cloning (since the solver does not add or remove elements from collections during solving); are you adding/removing from the collection when iterating it? See this Stack Overflow answer for details on resolving ConcurrentModificationException.

Thanks. I dont change collection when iterating it. I think it change from two threads, because not cloned. I run it with .withMoveThreadCount("8").
